# Foreach Loop with 2 variables

Tags: ios, foreach

I have created a foreach loop as follows

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSCalendar *c = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *treeDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"tree_1"];
        NSDateComponents *components = [c components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:treeDate toDate:nowDate options:0];
        NSInteger treeInt = components.hour;

        if(treeInt >= 0){
            [_tree1 setSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"TreeStump.png"]];
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have `tree_1` and `_tree1` increment with the loop. I am not sure how to add the `i` onto the variable in the 2 locations. So within the `@""` and the `setSpriteFrame` method

For example, `i == 3` the string `@"tree_4"` and variable `_tree4`.

Comment: You mean that when, for example, `i == 3` the string `@"tree_4"` and variable `_tree4` will be used?

Comment: @trojanfoe thats correct

Comment: Creating `@"tree_X"` from `i` (where X = i + 1) is easy (see `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`), but accessing `_treeX` is more difficult and you will have to make them properties and use KVC I reckon.

Comment: Note that it would be interesting to not recreate all the variables inside the loop (like the `NSUserDefaults`, the `NSCalendar`, etc)

Comment: Put the tree variables in an array. That way you can iterate the array and make everything much easier for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the following, as you are using `cocos2d` here you can easily access the sprites added in any parent you have.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tree_%i", i + 1];

if(treeInt >= 0){
    CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite*)[self getChildByTag:i+1];
    [sprite setSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"TreeStump.png"]];
}
```

Just you need to set tags for your sprite while creating it with the same sequence.

Answer (score 0):

First part is easy :

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tree_%i", i + 1];
```

The `%i` part is a type speciffier, which tells the underlying algorithm that it should expect and `int` parameter. You can use this like this :

```
NSDate *treeDate = [defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tree_%i", i + 1]];
```

The second part is a bit trickier, as you will have to modify your code. If you want to iterate over a couple of variables in a loop, the easiest thing to do is to put them in an array, and use the loop counter to acces items in it.
Seeing as your loop has 30 iterations, it would seem to be a good idea to store the `_treeX` variables in an array or other container from the start, so as not to have 30 variables. Putting things into arrays/containers gives you the felxibility of changing the number of items dynamically, without having to change a whole lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

For first part is simple you can use string with format:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tree_%i", i + 1];
```

For second can you use objective c run time feature to access instance variable with name.

```
Ivar class_getInstanceVariable(Class cls, const char * name)
```